# Performance reviews delayed

Tags: performance-reviews

My company announced that our performance reviews would be delayed for an indefinite amount of time due to them performing a market analysis to try and match salaries to market values. Sort of a good/bad situation because I believe many of the jobs at the company are underpaid but it leaves more uncertainty due to the time frame. (It will be paid retroactively still so that's good)

I had been waiting for this time of year to see what would happen with my performance review. Now that its not happening for a while, I'm not happy. I have gained lots of responsibilities this past year and believe I am not being compensated appropriately. I really don't like to complain and would rather keep my head down and work, but I don't want to wait around and then get disappointed once the reviews happen. In the meantime, I have been applying to other jobs but I would rather stay put with a better salary. Does it make sense to speak to my manager to see what he can do about this?

Answer (score 1):

It always makes sense to talk to your manager in a normal, non-confrontational manner. He/she might have more insight in the timeline, or a heads up on your standing.

On the other hand: reviews and feedback could just be done right now, with adjusting salaries done later after reviewing the market. Delaying the review too is a warning sign that some other consideration might be in play.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an excuse, market analysis if any should have been done in plenty of time, it's not like the reviews are something that just came up.

Depending on your circumstances this is something that would be worth pushing with your manager, especially if you're thinking of leaving.

I've never really cared what others make or procedures. If I expect more money I ask for it with the implication that if I don't get it I'll be gone. It's then the managers problem to find a way to keep me happy if they think I'm worth it. If you don't ask there is no incentive to give you anything.

The downside is that they may decide you're not worth it, so don't do it unless you are actually prepared to leave. Don't bluff. If you're going to go this route you jump in with both feet, anything less weakens any future negotiations.

Comment: @Dukeling no I mean 'don't bluff'... I'm not a believer in 'somewhat', any negotiation implies an ultimatum at it's most basic. Not 'I'd really like you to sort my issue out if you feel like it, or you can just disregard me if you want.' If you're not prepared to stand up, then you don't, standing up halfway up looks ridiculous and weak, not confident and assertive.

Comment: For context they did say the non-exempt employees reviews were very close to being ready

Comment: We're 'very close' to putting humans on Mars

Answer (score 0):

> Does it make sense to speak to my manager to see what he can do about
>   this?

The company announced the delay, not your manager. There's little to no chance he can speed things up. That's not how these things  work.

You can complain to your manager that you feel you are underpaid, but you can't be  surprised when the answer is the equivalent of "the reviews are delayed".

It's probably a good sign for you that salaries are being analyzed with respect to the market - particularly if you think you are underpaid compared to the market.

If it were me, and I like other aspects of the job, I'd stick around to see the outcome of the performance reviews. At worst, you'll still be able to find a new job and start from a higher base salary. At best, your new salary will be good enough to make it worth while for you to stick around.

I'm  assuming your performance has been good enough that you would expect a great performance review. If that's not the case and you are expecting to be disappointed, then you might as well get out once you find a new job.

Answer (score 0):

Any delay in compensation that isn't explained properly should raise suspicion that the company is in financial trouble.  Talking to your manager is unlikely to resolve this, since your manager either won't be in on it or will be under orders to deny it.  If you do bring it up with your manager, look for signs that your manager is uncomfortable with the talk.  If your company is publicly held, you might want to look at what's available for the shareholders.

If the company is in financial trouble, you do want to keep applying elsewhere, and you should accept an offer you like, if made.

This isn't completely fair to the company, but things like this do happen, and the employees will often not be notified.